# If the datatype of an attribute is BLOB, is this attribute a binary column?

Tags: mysql, binary, mysql-workbench, sqldatatypes

I am a starter at database design. Just wondering if I use BLOB to store a video or something, should I check "B" (Binary Column) in the checkbox of Mysql workbench for this attribute?

Comment: Sounds redundant, but seems like it would not hurt.  Do something, then show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

I Have a table :

```
CREATE TABLE tvid (
           n              NUMBER,
           vid            BLOB,
           attributes     CLOB,
           mimetype       VARCHAR2(80),
           filename       VARCHAR2(500),              
       vid_duration INTEGER,
           bitrate        INTEGER
    )
LOB ( vid ) STORE AS SECUREFILE;
```

create a directory object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY  vid_DIR   AS 'D:\videos';
GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY vid_DIR  TO mediauser;
```

You insert data >> vid1.MP4:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT  ON;
DECLARE
           f_lob BFILE := BFILENAME( 'vid_DIR', '‏‏‏‏vid1.MP4');
           b_lob BLOB;
BEGIN
           INSERT INTO TAUD (N,vid,attributes )
           VALUES ( 1, EMPTY_BLOB(),EMPTY_CLOB());
           SELECT vid INTO b_lob FROM TAUD WHERE N=1 FOR UPDATE;
               -- open the bobs.
           DBMS_LOB.open(f_lob, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
           DBMS_LOB.open(b_lob, DBMS_LOB.lob_readwrite);
               -- populate the BLOB from the audio file in the BFILE.
           DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(b_lob, f_lob, DBMS_LOB.getlength(f_lob));
           -- close the LOBs;
           DBMS_LOB.close(b_lob);
           DBMS_LOB.close(f_lob);
           COMMIT;
END;
```

My question:How do i add video attributes to the table?